# Unit test for sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client

I actually have a trouble with unitest using sitecore.fake.DB. I configed step by step flow document. But, when I run it and I have error. Please help me for this. Tks so much!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question so it contains text instead of screenshots? That will make it more readable and easier to find.